# this is currrentIndex index widgetBody UserInfoScreen user null........ probleam in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

When I code if _currrentIndex = index; _widgetBody =  UserInfoScreen(user: null,);

i try everything but i can't understand this error

But I need the users to get to the bottom navigation bar

first (when user == null) so I changed the code at my Wrapper() from if(user==null){LoginScreen()} to if(user==null){WelcomePage()}. In the welcome screen, user will be navigated to the bottom navigation bar (LoginScreen()) if they pressed they not wokring

```
void _onItemTapped(int index) async{
    setState(() {
      if(index == 0){
        _currrentIndex = index;
        _widgetBody = HomeScreen();
      }
      else if(index == 1){
        _currrentIndex = index;
        _widgetBody = SearchScreen();
      }
      else if(index == 2){
        _currrentIndex = index;
        _widgetBody = Center(child: Text('favourite'),);
      }
      else if(index == 3){
        _currrentIndex = index;
        _widgetBody =  UserInfoScreen(user: null,);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What exactly error says?

Comment: can you include sample full widget

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: widgetBody =  UserInfoScreen(user: null,); this give me error

Comment: this is firebase login system i add this for open other page but this give me error